# I18n in modern Cpp project

Tags: c++, localization, internationalization, gettext

I'm developing a modern C++ project, currently and mid-term alone, but at certain point as a FOSS project. Currently I'm at the point where I have to implement the functionality for internationalization.
I researched a bit and found out that spoken languages are a total mess. So there is no way to implement something like a i18n/l10n library by myself. It sums up to: Use gettext. (In my case the Boost.Locale wrapper)

So far so good, but the library requires me, to write the original/source text directly in the code. English is assumed.
As you probably noticed, I'm not a native English-man. My English is too bad to use it as source language - and I don't want this. To carry subtle humor for example a good knowledge of the language is needed.

Now I see 3 options:

1. `std::cout << gettext("Hallo Welt") << std::endl;`
2. `std::cout << gettext("Hello World") << std::endl;`
3. `std::cout << my_own_crappy_lib(HELLO_WORLD_ID) << std::endl;`

1) Means to write my native language in the code, that makes it impossible for non-Germans to develop with my codebase. It's ugly too, because I write English source code, English code documentation, but German locale strings.

2) Means to write English and hope that somebody will correct my typos and dismiss my humor.

3) Implement something by myself that maps some shorthand identifier to translations. But I'm totally unsure how to do this and how to handle plural forms etc.

Can you give me some hint how I shall continue?

OT: Please don't blame my laziness to learn proper English. I'm a big fan of the TV series Futurama and there you see that even professional translators are not able to translate a lot of jokes or subtle allusions.

Comment: I use something like `my_own_crappy_lib`.  I have a text string key and the default translation (English, for me).  Then I have a process that looks for the the key/English strings in the source code, extracts them into a file, send the file out to the translators, and use key-value substitution for the end-user's language.  The strings also have placeholders in them, like `${FILENAME}` which is used to substitute key-text _in situ_ in the translated string.

Comment: You can also `gettext("HELLO_WORLD_ID")` with (real) translation also for English.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) Change the base language of your project to German. English has the same plural rules as German, and your project will therefore "just work".

2) Change the base language of your project to "Broken English". You then have to find somebody that translates your original strings in broken English into proper English by providing an `en.po` that does this mapping.  It is your task then, however, to regularly write back the corrected English strings into the actual source code.

Option 1 is straight-forward but for an open-source project, you'll have trouble finding volunteers to translate your strings if the base language is not English.

Option 2 sounds scarier than it is. PO files contain references to the source files so that it is relatively easy to write back the corrected English messages into your codebase. Normally, it's just a mouse-click in the PO editor.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a simple i18n library in cpp, you can go check [this one.](https://github.com/Sinan-Karakaya/cpp-i18n/tree/main)

The library was made to be as simple as possible to use, and its usage was inspired from most i18n libraries you can find in React for example.

All you need are JSON files for your translations, and simply create an i18n::Translator variable. You'll be able to call your translations just like that:

```
i18n::Translator t;
t('title', 'homeScreen');    // in homeSreen.json => "title": "Your Title"
```

I am the creator of this library, and many more features and examples are listed on the README. Don't hesitate to give it a try.

Comment: Hi. Sorry that I misunderstood your post. I am all for learning new things, and any more details you could give me would be greatly appreciated. It is fine for you to not like what I have done, however, I would like if you could clarify what you meant by modern CMake and fixed version of dependencies. At what point did using fixed versions of dependencies is bad? Do you want your project to break because of breaking changes? Altough I do agree with their locations, which I've made a PR to move them. That leaves us with modern CMake. After looking online, I couldn't find much. Care to explain?